# Neo4j Cypher pattern comprehension and conditions

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In my Cypher query I have a following pattern comprehension:

```
[ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(ch1:Characteristic)<-[:SET_ON]-(v1:Value)-[:SET_FOR]->(childD) | 
  {characteristicId: id(ch1),  value: v1.value, valueType: ch1.valueType, visualMode: ch1.visualMode} ] AS valuedCharacteristics
```

I have added `parentCharacteristic` to my SDN 4 `Characteristic` entity:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Characteristic extends Votable {

    private final static String DEPENDS_ON = "DEPENDS_ON";

    @Relationship(type = DEPENDS_ON, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Characteristic parentCharacteristic;

...

}
```

Right now I need to extend my pattern comprehension and add a conditions in order to return the same `Characteristic` set as previously except those who have `parentCharacteristic != NULL` and pattern comprehension should also return `Characteristic` that have `ID` in the `{includeCharacteristicIds}` collection that I'll provide to this query as parameter.

In order to avoid all `Characteristic` without child `Characteristic` I have added following condition:

```
WHERE NOT ((ch1)<-[:DEPENDS_ON]-())
```

So the full pattern comprehension now looks like:

```
[ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(ch1:Characteristic)<-[:SET_ON]-(v1:Value)-[:SET_FOR]->(childD) WHERE NOT ((ch1)<-[:DEPENDS_ON]-()) | 
  {characteristicId: id(ch1),  value: v1.value, valueType: ch1.valueType, visualMode: ch1.visualMode} ] AS valuedCharacteristics
```

but how also in additional to this `Characteristic` list return `Characteristic` that have `ID` in the `{includeCharacteristicIds}` collection ?

Please help to extend this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just combine the two conditions with an OR statement like this...

```
WHERE NOT ((ch1)<-[:DEPENDS_ON]-()) OR id(ch1) IN myIDs
```

The WHERE in a pattern comprehension works just like a WHERE for a MATCH condition.